# Data migration tool configuration

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

I've installed the data migration tool (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-configure.html).
Followed the steps to configure it by creating a separate module and everything works fine.
but from the looks of it, I need to keep the credentials to the magento 1 and magento 2 databases in the configuration file that I've cloned and modified from the tool code base.
This does not look like a valid approach if I want to version my config file. I rather not have the credentials available in a repo.
Is there an out of the box way of moving the credentials outside the config file?

Comment: The config file can be located anywhere : bin/magento migrate:data --auto /path/to/migration-config.xml

Comment: I know. But i also need this for development because i am not migrating only core data. I hace custom and third party extensions related data. So i need a part of it versioned and only the credentials stored somewhere else

Comment: I guess you would have to modify the migration module to read the authentication data from a separate config file or data source.

Comment: I was keeping this as a backup measure. I hoped for some out of the box way of doing it. I guess I'll have to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes in the migration tool are instantiated via Object manager. This means they can be pluginized.

I ended up making an around plugin for each of the methods

- `Migration\Config::getSource()`
- `Migration\Config::getDestination()`.

In these methods I read the Magento 1 db credentials from somewhere else and the magento 2 credentials from the `env.php` file of the instance where the migration tool is installed.

This way I can leave the credentials in the config file empty. But the tags have to be there, otherwise the migration tool complains

Comment: What about the crypt_key? Do you commit that to your repo, or do you save it together with your M1 db credentials in an unversioned file?

Comment: Yes. That can be read from somewhere else also

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to add a plugin for the "getResourceConfig" method, e.g. `afterGetResourceConfig`.